# Using Comparator to sort the List of string

Tags: java, sorting, compare, comparator

I have string. BOMResult:

1|00022954|41.418\n
2|00022951|1.0\n
3|00022945|41.575\n
3|00022944|41.684\n
3|00022944|41.778\n
3|00022944|41.871\n
3|00022946|42.918\n
3|00022944|41.918\n
3|00022944|41.825\n
3|00022944|41.731\n
3|00022945|41.621\n
3|00022953|41.512\n
4|00022957|0.0\n
5|00022947|42.809\n
5|00022942|42.918\n
5|00022948|43.918\n
5|00022947|42.871\n
5|00022950|42.746\n
4|00022952|1.0\n
5|00022941|41.246\n
5|00020472|41.184\n
2|00022958|0.0\n
3|00022945|39.621\n
3|00022944|39.731\n
3|00022944|39.84 \n
3|00022944|39.949\n
3|00022944|39.887\n
3|00022944|39.793\n
3|00022945|39.684\n
3|00022956|39.512\n
4|00022959|1.0\n
5|00022941|40.762\n
5|00022943|40.699\n
4|00022957|0.0\n
5|00022947|42.809\n
5|00022942|42.918\n
5|00022948|43.918\n
5|00022947|42.871\n
5|00022950|42.746\n
3|00022949|40.996\n
3|00022944|39.996\n

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrPAj.png)

When Vertical bar(|) is delimited,

The first string is level.

The last string is the base on which to sort.

If the levels are equal, sort the string.

```
List<String> rowList = Arrays.asList(BOMResult.split("\n"));
Collections.sort(rowList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String array1[] = s1.split("\\|");
        String array2[] = s2.split("\\|");
        int i1 = Integer.parseInt(array1[0]);
        int i2 = Integer.parseInt(array2[0]);

        if (i1 == i2) {
            return Double.valueOf(array1[array1.length-1]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(array2[array2.length-1]));
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
BOMResult = String.join("\n", rowList);
```

Current Result:

```
1|00022954|41.418
2|00022951|1.0
3|00022953|41.512
3|00022945|41.575
3|00022945|41.621
3|00022944|41.684
3|00022944|41.731
3|00022944|41.778
3|00022944|41.825
3|00022944|41.871
3|00022944|41.918
3|00022946|42.918
4|00022957|0.0
5|00020472|41.184
5|00022941|41.246
5|00022950|42.746
5|00022947|42.809
5|00022947|42.871
5|00022942|42.918
5|00022948|43.918
4|00022952|1.0
2|00022958|0.0
3|00022956|39.512
3|00022945|39.621
3|00022945|39.684
3|00022944|39.731
3|00022944|39.793
3|00022944|39.84
3|00022944|39.887
3|00022944|39.949
4|00022957|0.0
4|00022959|1.0
5|00022943|40.699
5|00022941|40.762
5|00022950|42.746
5|00022947|42.809
5|00022947|42.871
5|00022942|42.918
5|00022948|43.918
3|00022944|39.996
3|00022949|40.996
```

I want to sort at the same level, even if the lines are different.

Expected Result:

```
1|00022954|41.418
2|00022958|0.0
3|00022956|39.512
3|00022945|39.621
3|00022945|39.684
3|00022944|39.731
3|00022944|39.793
3|00022944|39.84
3|00022944|39.887
3|00022944|39.949
4|00022957|0.0
4|00022959|1.0
5|00022943|40.699
5|00022941|40.762
5|00022950|42.746
5|00022947|42.809
5|00022947|42.871
5|00022942|42.918
5|00022948|43.918
3|00022944|39.996
3|00022949|40.996
2|00022951|1.0
3|00022953|41.512
3|00022945|41.575
3|00022945|41.621
3|00022944|41.684
3|00022944|41.731
3|00022944|41.778
3|00022944|41.825
3|00022944|41.871
3|00022944|41.918
3|00022946|42.918
4|00022957|0.0
5|00020472|41.184
5|00022941|41.246
5|00022950|42.746
5|00022947|42.809
5|00022947|42.871
5|00022942|42.918
5|00022948|43.918
4|00022952|1.0
```

Comment: Sorry, but your expected result is not sorted in any way? What is your sort criteria?

Comment: @DiabolicWords I'm Sorry, I modified the expected result. All I want to do is sort at the same level, even at different lines. 0.0 should precede 0.1 at the same level. (1|00022954|41.418, 2|00022958|0.0, 3|00022956|39.512, ..., 2|00022951|1.0, 3|00022953|41.512 ...) Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by creating a **data object for the records**
 (replace names with actual properties, i.e. `first`->`level`):

```
 public static class Data {
    private final int first;
    private final String second;
    private final double third;

    public Data(int first, String second, double third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }

    public int getFirst() {  return first; }
    public String getSecond() { return second; }
    public double getThird() {  return third; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return first + "|" + second + "|" + third;
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you can **sort** lists of such records by **chaining Comparators**.
Example (sort by first, then second, then third):

```
List<Data> list = new LinkedList<>();
list.add(new Data(1, "00022954", 41.418));
list.add(new Data(2, "00022951", 1.0));
list.add(new Data(3, "00022953", 41.512));
list.add(new Data(3, "00022945", 41.575));
list.add(new Data(3, "00022945", 41.621));

// shuffle to test sorting
Collections.shuffle(list);

// sort the data
Collections.sort(list, 
    Comparator.comparing(Data::getFirst)
        .thenComparing(Data::getSecond)
        .thenComparing(Data::getThird));

// output the data
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified the expected result and added image. The string is a child relationship with parents and should not be changed in order.

Answer (score 0):

You could merge first and last column in the same comparator as below :

```
Collections.sort(rowList, new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        String array1[] = s1.split("\\|");
        String array2[] = s2.split("\\|");
        Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(array1[0].trim());
        Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(array2[0].trim());

        return i1.compareTo(i2) + Double.valueOf(array1[array1.length-1]).compareTo(Double.valueOf(array2[array2.length-1]));

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I modified the expected result and added image. The string is a child relationship with parents and should not be changed in order.

Answer (score 0):

Ok then, try this :

```
Collections.sort(rowList, new Comparator<String>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
    String array1[] = s1.split("\\|");
    String array2[] = s2.split("\\|");
    Integer i1 = Integer.valueOf(array1[0].trim());
    Integer i2 = Integer.valueOf(array2[0].trim());
    int res = i1.compareTo(i2);
    if (res == 0) {
      Double d1 = Double.valueOf(array1[array1.length - 1]);
      Double d2 = Double.valueOf(array2[array2.length - 1]);
      return d1.compareTo(d2);
    }
    return res;

  }
});
```

Comment: Why does this work? Can you explain the code? Code-only answers are often not very helpful.